# Convert Li-Ion battery-powered toy to regular battery

Tags: batteries

I'm no elec. engineer; I just like to do little protects like this, so please help me out.

My son's RC car is powered by Li-Ion, and I'm sick and tired for him to have to recharge it everyday for hours only so he can play with it for 5 minutes before it dies again.

I thought: maybe if I can just convert it to normal battery it'll stay for longer, and I don't mind having to buy a pack of batteries every once in a while. But daily charging for just 5 minutes is ridiculous.

So here's the circuit as it is now.

[image: Current setup of Li-Ion battery]

USB charging has two wires go into the board. Then there's two 2-wire cables (red and green sets) that go back to the car.
Why do I have two sets of 2-wire cables back to the car? I thought it would just need (+) and (-) in just two wires... Why 4?

And... The two batteries in it are: 500mAh, 3.2V, 1.6Wh
What do I replace them with?

Is that all even a feasible/viable project?

Thanks.

Comment: Sanity check first : To flatten a 500mAh battery in 5 minutes takes (nominally) 6A. This will kill non-rechargeable batteries even faster. Not feasible. Btu if you can fit C cells as in JustMe's answer, you can fit bigger Li-Ion cells like 18650s, giving about 2 Ah for 4x the life. NOTE if they are 3.2V they are LiFePO4 so you may have to replace with similar, or risk damage from the slightly higher (3.7V) Li-Ion cells.

Answer (score 1):

If you get only five minutes of play out of the batteries, I suspect something is wrong with the batteries. My son and I have a Sand Monster RC car and we get 30 minutes or more out of the 6.4 V L-ion 1300 mAh battery pack it came with.

My suggestion is for you to get two 18650 L-ion cells and connect them in parallel, these cells are rated at 2600 mAh which will give you a lot longer than five minutes of play.

I have recently bought a few cell phone powerbanks very cheaply that contain 18650 L-ion cells. I am planning to convert these to extra battery packs for the RC cars.

However, if you go this route, open the power banks carefully so that you do not short circuit the cells, or buy powerbanks that have not been charged yet, like I did to be safer, however, you must still try your best not to short circuit anything. These cells can deliver very large currents which can become very dangerous in a very short while if short-circuited.

Comment: While I agree with you, I wouldn't recommend it to a layman, which OP seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

That's the board that receives control data and drives the motors for moving and steering. One set of two wires goes to motor that controls the steering angle and one set of two wires goes to motor that rotates the wheels.

You could try to replace the batteries with C or D cells that you can charge in an external charger. But we can't see if the current lithium batteries are in series or parallel, so we'd need more info to suggest how to successfully replace them.

Answer (score 0):

I would just buy bigger batteries. It'll take longer to charge but it'll last longer. The circuit was designed to work with that type of battery. If you want to use different batteries you can not use the USB charging it can cause serious damage!
If you take a picture of the top of the PCB so we can see the parts numbers of the ICs then we can give you more help.